# variadic class template can't compile

Tags: c++11, templates

```
template<typename... Types>
class Tuple;

// recursive case:
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
class Tuple<Head, Tail...>
{
 private:
  Head head;
  Tuple<Tail...> tail;
 public:
  // constructors:
  Tuple() {
  }
  Tuple(Head const& h, Tuple<Tail...> const& t)
    : head(h), tail(t) {
  }
  //...

  Head& getHead() { return head; }
  Head const& getHead() const { return head; }
  Tuple<Tail...>& getTail() { return tail; }
  Tuple<Tail...> const& getTail() const { return tail; }
};

// basis case:
template<>
class Tuple<> {
  // no storage required
};

int main()
{
    Tuple<int,double> (1,4.5);
}
```

compiling it with g++ 11.3.0, I get this errors:

**error: no matching function for call to ‘Tuple<int, double>::Tuple(int, double)’**

why does this error happen and how to fix them?

The whole compiler output is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Why did you remove the compiler output? Its valuable information.

Comment: added a picture of g++ output just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is using the wrong type:

```
Tuple(Head const& h, Tuple<Tail...> const& t)
    : head(h), tail(t) {
  }
```

You are not passing in `Tuple<Tail...>`s but `Tail...`s. Changing this to

```
Tuple(Head const& h, Tail const&... t)
  : head(h), tail(t...) {
}
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a constructor to end the recursion fixes this one:

```
Tuple(Head const& h)
: head(h) {
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind reply. your solution works when there are 2 template parameters. but if there are 3 template parameters, for example, Tuple<int,double,char> (1,4.5,'u'), similar error occur again. so the question is: how to implement a general variadic class template?